# Приходит пустая ObservableCollection в модуль

Tags: c#, binding, dependencyproperty

Не так давно начал работать с WPF, поэтому не судите за карявость :)

Подскажите как правильно передать ObservableCollection из основной формы, на дополнительную. Передавал строковую, с ней так проходит. На главной форме есть DataGrid, и в нее, через ItemSourse все нормально приходит(Коллекция).

### Код модуля UserControl

```
public partial class VDiagr : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public VDiagr()
    {
        Number2 = "";
        InitializeComponent();
        canvas = Canv;
    }

     public static readonly DependencyProperty Vectors_collection = DependencyProperty.Register("Vec2", typeof(ObservableCollection<Vectors>), typeof(VDiagr), new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<Vectors>(), OnPropertyChangedVector));

    public ObservableCollection<Vectors> Vec2
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<Vectors>)this.GetValue(Vectors_collection); }
        set { this.SetValue(Vectors_collection, value);
        }
    }

    public class Vectors
    {
        public double angle { get; set; }
        public SolidColorBrush brush { get; set; }
        public double lenght { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
    }

     public static void OnPropertyChangedVector(DependencyObject sourse, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        (sourse as VDiagr).ChangeVectors();
     }

     void ChangeVectors()
    {
        if (Vec2 != null)
        {
            Axis.Set(canvas, true, false, 5, false);
            foreach (var item in Vec2)
            {                    
                Vect.SetRad(canvas, new V() { angle = item.angle, brush = item.brush, length = item.lenght, text = item.text });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Xaml основного

```
<Window
x:Class="Vec.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:vdiagram="clr-namespace:VDiagram;assembly=VDiagram"
Title="MainWindow"
Width="470"
Height="470"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackPanel
        Grid.Column="0"
        Height="25"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBox
            x:Name="tx"
            Width="120"
            Height="23"
            Margin="3"
            TextChanged="tx_TextChanged"
            TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        <Button
            Width="75"
            Margin="3"
            Click="Button_Click_1"
            Content="Button" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Margin="0,30,0,0">
        <DataGrid
            x:Name="data_grid"
            Height="200"
            AutoGenerateColumns="True"
            ItemsSource="{Binding vectors2, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" />
    </StackPanel>
    <vdiagram:VDiagr
        Grid.Column="1"
        Number2="{Binding Num2, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
        List_vectors="{Binding List_vectors,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
        AncestorType=Window}}" />
      </Grid>
    </Window>
```

### Код основной формы

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged {

    public MainWindow()
    {          
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public class Vectors
    {
        public double angle { get; set; }
        public SolidColorBrush brush { get; set; }
        public double lenght { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Vectors> vectors1;

    public ObservableCollection<Vectors> vectors2 
    {
        set
        {
            vectors1 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(vectors2));
        }
        get
        {
            return vectors1;
        }
    }

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        vectors2 = new ObservableCollection<Vectors>
        {
            //Произвольное заполнение коллекции
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавьте в конструктор формы `DataContext = this;`

Comment: Не, не помогает(

Comment: Виноват, у вас другая проблема, да, но выше предложенная строчка позволит заменить это `Binding Num2, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}` на вот это `Binding Num2`.

Comment: А, да, спасибо)
Но все еще не понимаю как с коллекцией быть.
Причем он фиксирует приход новой коллекции, но она пустая

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вынесите класс с данными во внешку, в неймспейс, а не внутри класса, и давайте его переименуем, чтобы не путаться.

```cs
// названия публичных свойств должны быть с большой буквы
public class MyVector
{
    public double Angle { get; set; }
    public SolidColorBrush Brush { get; set; }
    public double Length { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Тогда он будет доступен и из основной формы, и из юзерконтрола одновременно. Не надо копировать код класса в каждый класс.

У вас проблема с именованием `DependencyProperty`

```cs
public static readonly DependencyProperty VectorsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Vectors", typeof(ObservableCollection<MyVector>), typeof(VDiagr), new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<MyVector>(), OnPropertyChangedVector));

public ObservableCollection<MyVector> Vectors
{
    get => (ObservableCollection<MyVector>)this.GetValue(VectorsProperty);
    set => this.SetValue(VectorsProperty, value);
}
```

В основной форме

```cs
public MainWindow()
{          
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
}

private ObservableCollection<MyVector> _vectors;

public ObservableCollection<MyVector> Vectors 
{
    get => _vectors;
    set
    {
        _vectors = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

```xml
<vdiagram:VDiagr Grid.Column="1" Vectors="{Binding Vectors}" />
```

Comment: Все сделал. Да, знаю что каряво было, быстро писал)
Все еще пустое приходит.

Comment: @Иван если вы сделали все правильно, пустая быть не может, это технически невозможно. Проверяйте названия всех переменных, приводите в порядок именования, возможно вы где-то что-то перепутали. Вы поняли, что такое "вынесите класс в неймспейс"? Обратите внимание, у вас не должно быть "класс в классе" вообще.

Comment: @Иван еще пустая может быть при первом вызове обработчика, когда контрол инициализируется. А при следующем вызове уже должна быть та, что надо.

Comment: И правда, немного некорректно перенес. Все работает.
Спасибо огромное! Ты гений :)
Целый день возился с этим.